# In JQuery, .html(var) vs .html(var.html())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax

This code is provided for context, please see below for my question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {

        var newItem = $("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>");
        $("#para2").html(newItem.html());
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.a { color: Navy; }
.b { color: Maroon; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list1">
        <li class="a">item 1</li>
        <li class="a">item 2</li>
        <li class="b">item 3</li>
        <li class="b">item 4</li>
    </ul>
<p class="a">This is paragraph 1</p>
<p id="para2">This is paragraph 2</p>
<p class="b">This is paragraph 3</p>
<p>This is paragraph 4</p>
</body>
</html>`
```

---

**The is the part I am interested in:**

```
var newItem = $("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>");
    $("#para2").html(newItem.html());
```

---

**It appears to be functionally equivalent to this:**

```
var newItem = $("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>");
    $("#para2").html(newItem);
```

The former method, I noticed in a video demonstration that teaches jQuery. As far as I know all that the added `.html()` part does is to *get* the matching element. To me, it doesn't seem like getting it in this case would help, since in  `var newItem = $("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>");` the $() already made it a Jquery object.

---

### **Question:**

Is there a meaningful and impactful difference between the two above methods, or is it just a matter of coding preference?

Comment: `$("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>");` is an additional overhead that can be avoided by simply appending a HTML-String to the element with the needed paragraph like: var newItem = "<p>This is a new paragraph</p>" and than `$("#para2").html( newItem  )`

Comment: Making an in-memory Element Object like `$("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>");` allows you to than apply other methods to that object like `.find()` etc, while using the String way (like I described above) will not be possible. Any way, having an Object element and getting it's HTML like `newItem.html()` will only get it's innerHTML context, not the whole Paragraph Element.

Answer (score 3):

`html()` serialises the HTML *inside* the element to a string.

In this case, the difference is that `$("#para2").html(newItem.html());` will give you some text and `$("#para2").html(newItem);` will give you a *paragraph* containing that text.

Since `#para2` is a paragraph, and HTML does not allow paragraphs to be nested, the latter would also generate invalid HTML.

---

If you weren't creating the paragraph from scratch at at the same time (e.g. if `var newItem = $("#existingParagraph");`), then you would also be *moving* the element rather than copying its content.

---

Since you are just changing the text in the element, there is no need to create a jQuery object in the first place.

This:

```
    var newItem = $("<p>This is a new paragraph</p>");
    $("#para2").html(newItem.html());
```

is equivalent to:

```
    $("#para2").html("This is a new paragraph");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. At first glance, I didn't quite understand your answer. Then I did a side-by-side comparison of both methods using firebug inspector. Yes indeed by omitting the extra `.html()`, it caused an extra `<p>` element.